# Cannot resolve constructor in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

EditText myeditText1;
EditText myeditText2;
Button myButton;

Double myfirstET1;
Double myfirstET2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    myeditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    myeditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
    final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myfirstET1 = Double.parseDouble(myeditText1.getText().toString());
            myfirstET2 = Double.parseDouble(myeditText2.getText().toString());
            final ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mList);

            if ((myeditText1.getText().length() > 0) && (myeditText2.getText().length() > 0)) {
                double oper1 = Double.parseDouble(myeditText1.getText().toString());
                double oper2 = Double.parseDouble(myeditText2.getText().toString());
                double result = oper1 / oper2;
                myTextView.setText(Double.toString(result));


                Double myyList[] = {oper1, oper2 + 1, oper2 + 1};

                ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList);
                mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            }

        }
    });
```

Upon creating the ListView and setting adapter to it, I'm getting error in ListAdapter.. How do I fix it OR whats the easy alternative for it?
I hope my moto is clear with the code I've written.

All suggestions are heartly appreciated.

Comment: Not a mind reader - what error?

Comment: Can you give a logcat of the error?

Comment: Getting red line in android studio in line-

ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList); mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` in anonymous class to refer to this actual Activity context as

```
 ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList);
 //                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and also mention the type and use `ArrayAdapter` not `ListAdapter`

```
 ArrayAdapter<Double> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this...);
 //         ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes I did.. I guess I need to post a screenshot of the error.. I'm attaching an screenshot too..

Comment: @user8747695 check the update , `ListAdapter` is not generic

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this

```
ArrayAdapter<Double> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList);
```

Comment: You are correct. An ArrayAdapter cannot be cast to a ListAdapter, but as ListView adapter only requires a BaseAdapter then you can pass in an ArrayAdapter. 
[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews]
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList);
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

or

```
ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(MainActivity.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myyList);
                mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

But make sure instead of this use MainActivity.this